# Failed audit: question needs editing

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I've just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5458922) audit, which references [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010763/how-to-use-fields-in-java-enum-by-overriding-the-method) question.

The recommended action was to leave the question as it is, or upvote. However, I think the question could do with at least a spelling/formatting edit.

What do you think?

Comment: It's been a while since I've failed a First Posts audit, but are you sure you clicked the edit button rather than flagging by accident?

Comment: @TheLostMind No but there are a couple of minor things that could do with being improved. Editing it to polish off those last few things  doesn't seem too unreasonable to me, and that's probably what I would have done as well.

Comment: @JonK - I don't find any major issues with the post.. What *edits* do you suggest?

Comment: @TheLostMind I'd probably start by either correcting the spelling of "beauteful", or removing it completely and replacing it with "the" (what makes code beautiful is highly subjective...). I'd probably then reword "but by ref to `someField` I get" to "But when I reference `someField` I get a compiler error stating:". Lastly I'd probably remove the spare newline between the enum declaration and the `FIRST` element. All minor individually, but would clearing those few things up be bad?

Comment: @JonK - Well.. You could do that.. But the changes aren't *major*. Anyways, it differs from person to person..

Comment: @TheLostMind It does indeed...and perhaps those changes would be too minor for a suggested edit - but it'd be pretty rare for a first post to come in that had *absolutely nothing* wrong with it. Failing an audit for attempting to edit seems a little harsh in this instance.

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion, the post *can* be edited, but doesn't really need to:

- Make `enum` a code block;
- Correct spelling of 'beauteful';
- Remove the code block in the error message and make it a blockquote;
- 'by ref' can be spelled out.

As said, these are possible changes, but I wouldn't feel the urge to do so. Also, don't worry too much if you fail an audit once. If it happens often, you should start question yourself.

Comment: Maybe he shouldn't worry about it. But the if this happens consistently in the audit system, then we should all worry about it.

Comment: That's what I said. I think *she* understands ;)

Comment: @ouflak, might be petty and/or chatty but...usually *they* is a safe bet. Even user pics can't be a sure way to determine a poster's sex. "Sexing" comments is more often than not a pointless addition/assumption.

Comment: @PatrickHofman As for my original question, would you consider the possible edits "too minor" to be worth doing, like some commenters above?

Comment: @kmoe: I would edit it.